# Is there a way to turn off all the tabs on the tool shelf in the node editor in verion 2.72?

Tags: interface, node-editor

I see there has been a similar question asked about this but it was for removing single tabs you didn't want. I want to turn all the tabs off in the node editor tool shelf back to the way it was set up in 2.71. Is there some where in preferences to do this with 1 click? or some way to copy the code from 2.71 to 2.72?

Comment: You will have to edit some Python scripts.